# ArcGIS calculate average value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, loop

I would like to get the average value of specific attributes. I have a table with columns like:

ID, P1, E1, Age1, P2, E2, Age2, P3, E3, AverageAgeP, AverageAgeE

Sometimes there is a value for P, sometimes there is value for E - otherwise it's NULL. I would like to calculate the average value for all cells of P using the value of the Age-field defined in this group. The same I would like to do with E.

The difficulties I see, is to select all P which are not NULL, summarize the age belonging to it and divide by the number of values used - of course excluding the NULL-values.

As I have more then 3000 records I need to do it automatically using ArcGIS 10.3 . Maybe using Python and loops...

Comment: If I have understood you correctly you do not need to do any python just use the [summary statistic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) tool making your age field the CASE field.

Comment: I had a look at the summary statistic tool. This looks exactly as what I need. I have solved my problem using Excel. I prepared the data, did the calculations and joined the dataset back to ArcGIS. I think the tool mentioned above will do the same in a much proper and quicker way.